# Comment blocks of code in c++

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm having difficulty formulating this question, and therefore, I can't search for the answer in google.
My question is whether a function exists which can auto-comment/auto-uncomment blocks of code. Or is there a way to automatically remove or ignore certain lines when the code is built?

Maybe it can be done with directives?

Comment: please ask another question

Comment: First of all, welcome to StackOverflow. I believe the down-votes were given because of the challenging grammar.  (No offense: I am sure you speak my language better than I speak yours!) I have taken it upon myself to translate the question as best I could. Hopefully I have retained the nature of the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are asking about `#if` which skips sections of code based on compiler settings.

Microsoft's documentation on the feature is [located on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew2hz0yd.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) note that this link may contain compiler specific rules (I didn't read through all of it).

Comment: i try to make question about self-modifying cpp code

Comment: @исламуриев: Changing your code based on runtime status is impossible as you aren't running the compiler at runtime. #if can be used with complex conditionals for compile time but if you want to do it at runtime you will need to use normal conditionals.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having difficulty understanding your question. Are you looking for a shortcut to automatically comment out a section of code? If so, consider this, from the Codeblocks manual:

```
Comment highlighted code   | Ctrl-Shift-C 
Uncomment highlighted code | Ctrl-Shift-X
```

Comment: for example we have a block with the iteration, in which if else insruction.
i need in fuction which change code when it run for escape if else instruction in some moments

Comment: `if(thisConditionIsTrue) return;`
Put this line of code inside the loop where you want it to escape in certain conditions.